# ApexCharts Line Chart join between null values

Tags: reactjs, apexcharts

I am using the line chart with null values, and I noticed that the current implementation is that it leads to disconnected lines (meaning that there would be no lines between 2 points that has a null value between them). However, I am wondering if it is possible to implement it such that it links the two lines together (sort of treating it like there's no null value there and just connecting the two points together, skipping past the column with the 'null' value)

Here is a photo
[image]

For eg, I would like to connect the blue line fully, meaning it should connect from the '0' point to the '12.5' point while skipping the column in between due to 'null' value.